# Shopping days till christmas counter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

How to calculate shopping days till christmas counter in jQuery. need to add to website.
need quick and dirty. no partiaulcar date it needs to correspond to

needs to ignore weekends of course - or maybe not since its for a website. hmm

cant believe there isnt one on here already.

happy holidays everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily build a function to get the number of days left until a date:

```
function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
  var now = new Date(),
      dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
      days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days

  return Math.round(days);
}

daysUntil(2009, 12, 25); // 19 days!!
```

Comment: I would suggest making the return function `Math.ceil(days)` because 10.2 days is still technically 11 days.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/countdown2) to display countdowns, it's pretty simple to set up.  A usage example is available on [this page](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Comment: as i was actually writign this i realized the normal 'shopping days' rules probably dont apply (i.e. ignoring weekends)

Answer (score 0):

Modified CMS's code a bit:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript">
function daysUntil() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = '12';
    var day = '25';
    dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
    days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days
    document.getElementById('xmas').innerHTML = 'Days until Christmas: ' + Math.round(days);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="xmas"></div>
<script language="javascript">
daysUntil();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```